# D(R) versus Ho(HR)?

Tags: homotopy-theory, derived-categories

Given an algebraic ring, how is its derived category related to the homotopy category of HR modules?

Thanks.  This is essentially a reference request, since I know there may be a lot (or nothing) to say about this.

Comment: They coincide, see Shipley's "HZ-algebra spectra are differential graded algebras".

Comment: Well, that's pretty much it, so I guess I should delete this question, haha.

Comment: EKMM also has a discussion of this that I would recommend.